# Maximal torus and application in prime graph

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory

I am studying  papers about  " Prime graph" , for example "Prime graph  components of finite groups" [ williams], " Groups with complete prime graph  connected components" [ Lucido and moghaddanfar]. But I do not  understand some of scientific terms in papers to relate this matter. For example, concepts like torus, maximal tori. 
 Can someone explain these terms? How these concepts are used in these articles?

Comment: They are talking about maximal tori in finite groups of Lie type. See e.g. the books by Carter (http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=794307) or Malle-Testerman (http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2850737).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that each torus is a maximal abelian subgroup and so the prime divisors of $|T|$ are mutually adjacent in the prime graph of $G$.

So knowing the order of maximal abelian subgroups of a simple group give many adjacency in the prime graph.

Only one need to determine the adjacency between the characteristic of the field related to the simple group of Lie type to determine the prime graph of a simple group.

I hope that it be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, very good answer.How can I find the order of maximal abelian subgroups of a simple group? Where can I find information about simple groups that are easy to understand.

Comment: You can see the books where introduced by Francois Ziegler in the previous section.

Comment: Also you can use the Wilson's book about the simple group which is a very nice text.